# how can i convert a date like dd-mm-yyyy into ISO date format, to store in a mongoDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, datetime, mean

In my mean stack app, i have  data on a date basis. In angular side, i used a date picker to get/set the date that the read/write of Data to be handled. The date picker produce date of the form "dd-mm-yyyy". What is the easiest way to convert this into mongodb understandable format, and back.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: toISOString() will produce the ISO string from a Date object. So how to convert a date like 29-8-2014 into the date object.

Comment: On the left-side of the page I've linked, there's a bunch of links to Date object documentation ... See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: i added a verbose solution..

Comment: Can you make the datepicker produce the date as `yyyy-mm-dd` string instead?

Comment: i am using a library, mero ui css, it's very rich and there are all kind of date pickers available. But for me dd-mm-yyyy string is the most natural and comfortable.

Comment: I believe Date objects in Javascript are formed using YYYY-mm-dd as default. You may have to manipulate the your entry format before converting.

Answer (score 7):

```
var str = "29-1-2016";
darr = str.split("-");    // ["29", "1", "2016"]
var dobj = new Date(parseInt(darr[2]),parseInt(darr[1])-1,parseInt(darr[0]));
                         // Date {Fri Jan 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530(utopia standard time)
console.log(dobj.toISOString());
                         //2016-01-28T18:30:00.000Z
```

This will do it,  but is there an easier way..!!

- Also please comment on why in the isodate format i get 2016-01-28T...., other than 2016-01-29T.....

Answer (score 1):

You could use this solution *(worked in my case)*-

Firstly, use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js) in your code, include it in your project. Now, The time string that you are getting here `var str = "29-1-2016";` and along with **moment.js** use the below code and you're good to go -

```
var str = "29-1-2016";
var time = moment(str).toISOString();
\\ This variable time is now converted into ISO string
```

Comment: It just does *not* work (tested with `moment.js 2.26.0`)

Comment: `2016-01-29` (`yyyy-mm-dd`) works, so it doesn't answer OP's question